# Adding the -M flag to g++ causes a file format not recoginzed error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Adding the `-m` flag to g++ causes a `file format not recognized; treating as linker script`, which in turns causes a syntax error when linking.

I'm using this makefile:

```
# Compilers
CXX = g++
#CXX = clang++
CC = gcc

UNAME := $(shell uname)

# Directories used for input and output
SRCDIR = src/src
BUILDDIR = build
EXEDIR = bin
INCLUDEDIR = src/include
VERBOSE = 0

# Debug flags
ifeq ($(VERBOSE), 1)
    CXX_FLAGS += -M
endif

# Enable all warnings but format and unused variables
CXX_FLAGS += -Wall -Wno-format -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-varargs -c -g -O0 -fbuiltin -fpermissive -std=c++14 -I include -I $(INCLUDEDIR)

OUTPUT_NAME = Test

# Where the sources are located
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
SRCS += $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*/*.cpp)

CSRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)

# Where the compiled objects are located
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(BUILDDIR)/%.o, $(SRCS))
COBJS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(BUILDDIR)/%.o, $(CSRCS))

# Linking all the .o files and with the libs
build: $(OBJS) $(COBJS)
    $(CXX) $^ $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o ./bin/$(OUTPUT_NAME)

# Compiling all the .cpp files into .o files
$(OBJS): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"

$(COBJS): $(BUILDDIRT)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"

# Running the created exe
.PHONY: run
run:
    ./$(EXEDIR)/$(OUTPUT_NAME)
```

In `src/src` I have two files, `test.cpp` and `foo.cpp`.

`test.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "cstdio"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo f;
    int b = f.bar(2);

    printf("%d", b);
    return 0;
}
```

`foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo() {

}

Foo::~Foo() {

}

int Foo::bar(int c) {
    return c + c;
}
```

The `.h` file for `foo.cpp` is in `src/include`:

`foo.h`:

```
#ifndef _FOO_H
#define _FOO_H

class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    int bar(int c);
};

#endif
```

Calling `make build` compiles the code fine, and I get the output I expect, 4. But by calling `make VERBOSE=1 build` (which turns on the -M flag for g++) I get

`/usr/bin/ls:build/foo.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script`

`usr/bin/ld:build/foo.o:1: syntax error`

I'm confused as to why enabling the `-M` flag would cause this, because I thought that `-M` output the dependencies of the program. If someone could point me in the correct direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-M` flag makes the compiler output dependencies *to wherever it would otherwise have put its object file*, as Barry explained in his answer. It does not print the dependencies on screen. Additionally, it disables C/C++ compilation altogether -- only preprocessing is performed.

If you were using the `-M` option to generate dependency files as input for `make`, you could use the [`-MD`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-MD-1085) option to make the compiler output dependencies to a `.d` file alongside the object file. (In your case, for instance, that would make it generate a `foo.d` file along with the object file `foo.o`.)

Since it sounds like you just want to print the dependencies to the screen, though, you can use the `-MF` option to redirect the dependency output, e.g.

```
-M -MF /dev/stdout
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, of course! You're right that [`-M`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-M-1076) changes the output of gcc from an object file to a rules file that make can import. But then you're using those result files *not* as dependency files to be `-include`d into your makefile, but as object files!

In short, you're doing something like this:

```
g++ -c foo.cxx -o foo.o
g++ -c bar.cxx -o bar.o
g++ -o exe foo.o bar.o
```

which works. And then changing it to:

```
g++ -M -c foo.cxx -o foo.o
g++ -M -c bar.cxx -o bar.o
g++ -o exe foo.o bar.o
```

You're naming the results of those operations `foo.o` and `bar.o`, but they're not object files, and when you try to link them together, the linker will fail because... they're not object files. This should be extremely clear if you try to `cat` your "verbose" build object files and see what they actually look like.